# Android Facebook Dialog

Tags: java, android, facebook, dialog

I have integrated Facebook into my app. However, instead of bringing it up in a dialog, it opens full screen. I was wondering if anyone would know of a way to change this to dialog.

FaceBook Handler Class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /*
     * Get existing access_token if any
     */      
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if(access_token != null) 
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

    if(expires != 0) 
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);


    if (facebook.isSessionValid()) 
      postFacebookMessage();

    else {
      facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"publish_stream"}, new Facebook.DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            Toast.makeText(FacebookConnector.this, "Facebook error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            Toast.makeText(FacebookConnector.this, "Facebook dialog error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

            @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                postFacebookMessage();
            Toast.makeText(FacebookConnector.this, "Thank You For Sharing!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {Toast.makeText(FacebookConnector.this, "Facebook authorization cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    }
} 

private void postFacebookMessage() {

  AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
  Bundle params = new Bundle();
  params.putString("message", MSG);
  params.putString("picture", "http://meanwhileinwv.com/meanwhile.png");
  mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new FacebookPostListener(), null); }    

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

The code above produces the following result:

[image]

I would like it to be a dialog that the facebook window opens into. I have achieved this with my Twitter code:

[image]

Comment: would you mind sharing a miniproject how did you achieve the facebook login?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call authorization with additional parameter **Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH**, like this:

```
facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"publish_stream"}, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new Facebook.DialogListener() { ... });
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Is there a way to give it rounded corners? If not, no big deal, just curious.

Comment: You can make your changes in *FbDialog.java** from Facebook SDK and apply the style you need.

Comment: what would the style be? I'm not the best at the graphical end of Android

Comment: I mean you can change code in **FbDialog.java** where dialog layout is defined (so you may set your background or smth else). Sorry, now I can't help you with code example.

Comment: Would really love to know if you found a way to do this.