# Post text on facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I wish to post a text / link defined by me on my wall. The way I'm doing, okay opening the box wall and posting a text set time. I want to post a text as if it were a variable.
Eg String text = "Text to be posted"
and this text appear on my wall. Any idea?

```
 public void postToWall() {

    facebook.dialog(cxt, "feed",new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Profile", response);
            String json = response;

            try {
                // Facebook Profile 
                JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                // nome usu�rio
                final String name = profile.getString("name");

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Comentário enviado com sucesso" + "Name: " + name, 
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: have you followed the tutorial on facebook's developers page?

Comment: Not in this case. But is there any way to make this post a text from a variable set for me, as I described?

Comment: will my case is similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336503/android-facebook-dialog